# Split vertically window at startup with .vimrc

Tags: vim

As the title suggests, how to split the page vertically on startup with .vimrc?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want a vertical split when vim starts up, add an autocommand to your *.vimrc*:

```
au VimEnter * vsplit
```

Note that vim will do this for you if you're opening multiple files on the command line: use the `-O` switch.

> -o[N]                Open N windows (default: one for each file)
>
> -O[N]                Like -o but split vertically

So you can start vim like this:

```
$ vim -O MyPage.html MyPage.css
```

And vim will open with those two files both visible in a vertical split.

Comment: Thanks I've been searching the whole day how to do this from .vimrc.I don't know vimscript yet !

Comment: Very nice. Just to add a link for autocommand stuff http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html. I can put another line of `au VimEnter * Explore` below what your suggest, then it will show file explorer on the left every time you start up vim.